# Prove replacement of dummy variable in summation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Spent several hours working on this problem:

*Apply the indicated change of variable, if possible.*

$\langle\sum{i}:|i|<5: i\mathbf{div} 2\rangle$ with $i \mapsto 2*i$ (that is, *f.i* = 2*i)

In *A Logical Approach to Discrete Math by David Gries*,  **Change of dummy** theorem is defined:

[image]

My interpretation of the **theorem** is as follows. Function *f*, in this case, $f(i) = 2*i$, has an inverse in the range of specification (I need to compose R with f, to get $R(f) = |2*i*| < 5$). This is the set **{-2,-1,0,1,2}**.

When I map *f* with this set as a domain, I get **{-4,-2,0,2,4}**. Hence, *f* is a bijective function. And I think it is possible to change that dummy variable with proposed function.

Is this reasoning correct? Is the theorem saying that *f* needs to be a bijective function with $R(f)$ as its domain?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.D: By the way, what does it mean x = f.y, before theorem definition?

Comment: The dot ($.$) is sometimes used to denote function application. I've only ever seen it used this way once, in a textbook on computation theory. In more common notation, this says $x=f(y)\iff y=f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Your notation clarifies that matter. Could you give me an example with an actual function?

Comment: The inverse of a function $f$ is the function $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$. For example $f(x)=3x\implies f^{-1}(x)=x/3$. Not every function has a [total] inverse. If $f$ is a bijection, then $f(x)=y\iff x=f^{-1}(y)$, otherwise $f$ has a partial inverse. For example both $\sqrt{x}$ and $-\sqrt{x}$ are partial inverses of the function $f(x)=x^2$. Since $f(x)=3x$ is a bijection (from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$), $f(x)=3x\iff x=f^{-1}(3x)$.

Comment: That is really clear. Thank you. In your first comment, in the book says $x=f(y)\iff y=f^{-1}(x)$ but you switched variables. Is it the same concept ?

Comment: Yes, the labelling of variables does not affect anything. As long as you make sure not to use the same symbol for two different variables, you can swap out any symbol for a different one - e.g. $a$ instead of $x$, Ж instead of $f$, etc.